# How to view a snappy file?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

My OS is Windows 10.
I work with AWS dynamodb->Athena->S3.
My colleague has downloaded one table to *.snappy file and sent me.
How can I view this file? When I open it in Windows Notepad++ it seems compressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(compression)) is a compression format. There is a quite high chance that the compressed file is a .parquet so you can try [ParquetViewer](https://github.com/mukunku/ParquetViewer) which supports snappy decompression out of the box.

Comment: I have tested it . It cannot read my snappy file, gives an Unexpected error.